# Flutter intent issue in MainActivity

Tags: flutter, android-intent

I'm trying to add a functionality to my Flutter Android app so that I can receive intents from a scheduled alarm (or any other app) and show a specific page to the user. I reviewed the official documentation as well as other third party projects, as I kept getting errors and wasn't sure of what need to be done in MainActivity.java and AndroidManifest.xml.

Now I'm trying with a completely new app, just as a test and only changing MainActivity.java according to the Flutter documentation that can be found [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter). This is the same approach used in other projects and blogs I could find.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
MainActivity.java:22: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
                                           ^
```

I can get rid of that error if I comment out that line and replace it for a the default method that appeared in the file when it was created:

```
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
}
```

But then I need to replace some imports for that to work (*io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity* instead of *io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity*) and start getting new errors as a result (e.g.: *getFlutterView()* in MethodChannel is not found).

I believe this should be easier to accomplish and there must surely be something I'm not doing correctly. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Seems some things have changed. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50457 might help. `getFlutterView()` is now `flutterEngine.getDartExecutor()` also check imports like `io.flutter.plugin...` vs `io.flutter.embedding`.

Answer (score 0):

found this to work after upgrading to flutter `1.17` stable channel

```
 @Override
 public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);


    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler(
                    (call, result) -> {
                        // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                        if (call.method.contentEquals("someMethod")) {
                            result.success("reply");
                        } else {
                            result.notImplemented();
                        }
                    }
            );
```

not sure if you also need to use

`cleanUpFlutterEngine` to clean method channel registration.

Comment: How does the MethodChannel thing relate to OP's question?